# How does jmeter starts sending requests to server

Tags: server, request, jmeter

If Thread: 100, Rampup: 1 and Loop count: 1 is the configuration, how will jmeter start sending requests to the server?

Request will be sent 1 req/sec or all requests will be sent all at once to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter will send requests **as fast as it can**, to wit:

1. It will start all threads (virtual users) you define in [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) within the ramp-up period (in your case - 100 threads in 1 second)
2. Each thread (virtual user) will start executing [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) which are present in the Thread Group upside down (or according to the [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers))
3. When there are no more samplers to execute or loops to iterate the thread will be shut down
4. When there are no more active threads left - JMeter test will end.

With regards to **requests per second** - it mostly depends on your application response time, i.e.

- if you have 100 virtual users and response time is 1 second - you will get 100 requests/second
- if you have 100 virtual users and response time is 2 seconds - you will get 50 requests/second
- if you have 100 virtual users and response time is 500 milliseconds - you will get 200 requests/second
- etc.

I would recommend [increasing (and decreasing) the load **gradually**](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide), this way you will be able to correlate increasing load with increasing throughput/response time/number of errors, etc. while releasing all threads at once will not tell you the full story (unless you're doing a form of [spike testing](http://www.testingperformance.org/definitions/what-is-spike-testing), in this case consider using [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer))

Answer (score 0):

JMeter's  [ramp-up period](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) set as 1 means to start all 100 threads in 1 second.

This isn't recommended settings as describe below

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.
>
> Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).
>
> Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.

See also [Can i set ramp up period 0 in JMeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26250839/can-i-set-ramp-up-period-0-in-jmeter)

> bear in mind that with low rampup and many threads, you may be limited by local resources, so your results may be a measurement of client capability rather than server.